# Neo4j: Count items belonging to two different connected categories

Tags: neo4j

I want to count and compare the number of items of two connected categories, but the numbers don't seem to match.

Let's say I have a graph such as:

```
CREATE (o1:Object {name:"CategoryA"})-[:CONNECTS_TO]->(o2:Object {name:"CategoryB"}),
       (i1:Instance {name:"Item1"})-[:IS_A]->(o1),
       (i2:Instance {name:"Item2"})-[:IS_A]->(o2),
       (i3:Instance {name:"Item3"})-[:IS_A]->(o2)
```

Where Object1 is connected to Object2 and at the same time Object1 is associated with Item1 and Object2 is associated with Item2 and Item3.

Then I want to count the number of items for each object:

```
MATCH (o1:Object)-[:CONNECTS_TO]->(o2:Object),
      (ix)-[:IS_A]->(o1), 
      (iy)-[:IS_A]->(o2) 
WITH o1, o2, COUNT(ix) AS o1_count, COUNT(iy) AS o2_count 
RETURN o1.name, o1_count, o2.name, o2_count
```

I would have expected a result of:

```
"CategoryA" 1   "CategoryB" 2
```

But actually I get:

```
"CategoryA" 2   "CategoryB" 2
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see what's going on if you just return the results of your match:

```
MATCH (o1:Object)-[:CONNECTS_TO]->(o2:Object),
      (ix)-[:IS_A]->(o1), 
      (iy)-[:IS_A]->(o2)
RETURN o1, o2, ix, iy
```

You'll get this back:

```
╒════════════════════╤════════════════════╤════════════════╤════════════════╕
│"o1"                │"o2"                │"ix"            │"iy"            │
╞════════════════════╪════════════════════╪════════════════╪════════════════╡
│{"name":"CategoryA"}│{"name":"CategoryB"}│{"name":"Item1"}│{"name":"Item3"}│
├────────────────────┼────────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────┤
│{"name":"CategoryA"}│{"name":"CategoryB"}│{"name":"Item1"}│{"name":"Item2"}│
└────────────────────┴────────────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────┘
```

There are exactly two patterns which fit your match, and the only difference in these patterns is which node is used for `iy`. The rest of the nodes in the pattern are the same.

For your full query here, because there are two possible patterns where `o1` and `o2` are the same (these are the non-aggregation variables), the counts are going to be 2 for each (it's just that for one of them, `ix`, it's the same node each time).

What you actually want are the counts of distinct nodes in the pattern:

```
MATCH (o1:Object)-[:CONNECTS_TO]->(o2:Object),
      (ix)-[:IS_A]->(o1), 
      (iy)-[:IS_A]->(o2) 
WITH o1, o2, COUNT(distinct ix) AS o1_count, COUNT(distinct iy) AS o2_count 
RETURN o1.name, o1_count, o2.name, o2_count
```

This gets you the results you want, since there is only one distinct `ix` node in the paths found, and two distinct `iy` nodes in the paths found.

A better approach is to not even use the count aggregation, and instead get the degree of the :IS_A relationship from each node:

```
MATCH (o1:Object)-[:CONNECTS_TO]->(o2:Object)
WITH o1, o2, size(()-[:IS_A]->(o1)) AS o1_count, size(()-[:IS_A]->(o2)) AS o2_count 
RETURN o1.name, o1_count, o2.name, o2_count
```